# Why won't my xbox360 download any compatibility emulators?

Tags: xbox-360, backwards-compatibility

I have the latest dash, but when I insert an original xbox disk (confirmed on wiki to be compatible) I just get an error to install additional software without any option or instruction as to what this software is.

The games were Fable: The lost chapters and GTA: Vice city. They were undamaged. Both show up on [the List of Xbox games compatible with Xbox 360 wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Xbox_games_compatible_with_Xbox_360). I have plenty of space on my 250GB hard drive.

Comment: what game is it? is the disk damaged? can you try another xbox disk? did you confirm that it is OFFICIALLY compatible?

Comment: @KiloJKilo, updated with the information requested

Comment: Do you have a Hard Drive, or are you using memory unit for saving?

Comment: @APrough, I am using a 250GB drive

Comment: How is the network that you're trying to connect with setup?

Comment: @FCTW it is a wired network. It is DSL to the outside world.

Comment: Do you have an official Microsoft hard drive, or did you modify a normal computer hard drive for use in a 360?

Answer (score 1):

You could try downloading the compatibility pack [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=12129). I don't remember having to do this, I think it auto updated but that was years ago and maybe since the newer releases it wasn't something that was overtly needed so they didn't provide it automatically.